# How to update dependencies and dev dependencies in package.json file?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

In my `package.json` file i want to update `dependencies` & `devdependencies` in my project.

I don't know how to update it

Comment: `npm update` simple as that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will post 2 approaches

1. To update package.json in addition to the local modules, run

   ```
   npm update --save-dev
   ```
2. To update to a new major version all the packages, install the npm-check-updates package globally:

   ```
   npm install -g npm-check-updates
   ```

   then run it:

   ```
   ncu -u
   ```

   This will upgrade all the version hints in the package.json file, to dependencies and devDependencies, so npm can install the new major version.

   You are now ready to run the update:

   ```
   npm update
   ```

   **note** *`npm update` will ignore devDependencies unless the -- dev flag is added.npm update will not upgrade to the latest major version. It makes sense since major releases frequently introduce breaking changes, and it needs to be handled with caution.*

Comment: In your note, you mention the `-- dev` flag; I think you meant the `--save-dev` flag?

Comment: Does not work in my case. Both devDependencies won't update with `--save-dev`. Is there any other reason npmwould skip these?

Comment: Just use `--save` flag, it does the job

Answer (score 0):

You can update all `dependencies` and `devDependencies` to their respective new major versions by running the following commands:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

Please note that `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` is recommended because there might be some errors (due to issues with resolving the dependency tree) while you install new package versions using the approach above. If you run into any further error with any particular package, just manually choose the right version for that specific error-causing package.